# Programmatically re - center button in RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, button, android-relativelayout

I am making a game where the user is supposed to try to press a button before the timer has reached one second, and the button moves to a random position every time the user clicks it.
At the start the button is centered, but will obviously be randomly placed when the game ends. I have a restart button which I want to re center the button so the game can start over.

Any help?

Comment: What code do you have? What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried setting the buttons layout params to centerinparent, centerhorizontally and centervertically. @Einar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the [View#setTranslationX() and View#setTranslationY()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTranslationX(float)) methods or the  [View#setX() and View#setY()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setX(float)) methods for this.  It's far easier to use these property methods instead of using the `View#setLayoutParams()` framework.

The `View#setTranslationX/Y` will move the View a set number of pixels relative to its current position on screen.  So `view.setTranslationX(5)` will move it five pixels to the right, `view.setTranslationX(-5)` will move it five pixels to the left, `view.setTranslationY(5)` will move it down five pixels, and `view.setTranslationY(-5)` will move it up five pixels.  `view.setTranslationX(0)` will move it back to its original position on the x-axis and `view.setTranslationY(0)` will move it back on the y-axis.

The `View#setX/Y()` methods will move the view to a set point on the parent View with the pivot being on the top left corner of the view. So `view.setX(0)` will move it to the left side of the parent View and `view.setY(0)` will move it to the top of the parent View.  You can get the parent View width and height to determine where to put them on the View. You can use `view.getX()` and `view.getY()` to retrieve their original locations.

Comment: setTranslationX(0) and setTranslationY(0) worked perfectly. Thanks! :D